# Event horizon around branes

Tags: gravity, event-horizon, branes

I'm wondering if a brane is a massive topological defect, does it have an event horizon?
Is it related to the effect capuring matter fields on the brane?

Thanks for the answers

Comment: What kind of branes are we talking about here (which theory)?

Comment: General relativity with extra dimensions.

Comment: Monopoles and cosmic strings are also defects, they don't necessarily have event horizons. Branes with horizons are called black branes

Comment: Kosm: does this mean branes can be massless although they contain matter field(s)?

Comment: @RobertSzili   branes may or may not contain matter

Comment: Kosm: understood. But is it possible that a massless brane contains massive excitations? I mean the excitations are massive inside the brane.